# File upload works in local but not in server

Tags: c#, .net-core

this code works once in server and after that again we click the submit button server shows "www.example.com can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("AboutId,Title,ImagePath,ShortContent,LongContent,RecordStatus,CreatedDate,Seokeywords")] AboutTbl aboutTbl, IFormFile FormFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //----
        string newFileName;
        var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(FormFile.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
        int index = fileName.LastIndexOf('.');
        string onlyName = fileName.Substring(0, index);
        string fileExtension = fileName.Substring(index + 1);

        var abtrepo = _aboutTblRepository.FindwithImagePath(fileName);
        if (abtrepo != null)
        {
            newFileName = onlyName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddHHmmtt") + "." + fileExtension;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images", "About", newFileName);
            aboutTbl.ImagePath = newFileName;
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                
                 FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images", "About", FormFile.FileName);
            aboutTbl.ImagePath = fileName;
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                 
                FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
        //----

        byte recordStatus = (byte)Common.CommonEnums.RecordStatus.ACTIVE;
        aboutTbl.RecordStatus = (byte?)recordStatus;

        DateTime createdDate = DateTime.Now;
        aboutTbl.CreatedDate = createdDate;

         _aboutTblRepository.CreateAbout(aboutTbl);
        _notyf.Success("About added successfully");

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(aboutTbl);
}
```

this is AboutTblRepository

```
public void CreateAbout(AboutTbl aboutTbl)
{
    _context.Add(aboutTbl);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Interface IAboutTblRepository

```
public void CreateAbout (AboutTbl aboutTbl);
```

Comment: 500 means the server code threw an excepction. You have no error handling or logging code, so there's no way to know what happened. Add a `try/catch` block and log any errors

Comment: Your algorithm for generating "unique" filenames is inadequate if run more than once in the same minute, and you are creating the new filestream with FileMode.Create, so the error is *probably* that you are trying to create the same filename twice - but you should use exception handling and logging to confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently i found that error

i just removed

```
var abtrepo = _aboutTblRepository.FindwithImagePath(fileName);
        if (abtrepo != null)
        {
        }
       else
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "images", "About", FormFile.FileName);
            aboutTbl.ImagePath = fileName;
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                 
                FormFile.CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
```